# How to split a row into 2 columns based based on my example

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So let's say I have the following table and desired output:

[image]

So basically I want 1 order number row with corresponding CAD and Amend columns.  Here's what I tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SUBSTRING(od.OrderNo,1,5) AS [OrderNo],
CASE
  WHEN od.PartNo LIKE 'cad appr%' THEN od.PartNo END AS [CAD Appr.?],
CASE
  WHEN od.PartNo LIKE 'cad appr%' THEN od.DueDate END AS [Appr. Date],
CASE 
  WHEN od.PartNo LIKE 'amend%' THEN od.PartNo END AS [Amend. Sent?],
CASE
  WHEN od.PartNo LIKE 'amend%' THEN od.DueDate END AS [Amend. Sent Date]
FROM OrderDet od
WHERE od.PartNo LIKE 'cad appr%'
  OR od.PartNo LIKE 'amend%'
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

So obviously it's not working like I desire, it's splitting into 2 rows for very order number that has both a CAD Approved and Amendment Sent PartNo, and I think understand why it's doing that after thinking about it.  I suppose a CASE statement is not the way to go, but I'm a bit lost as to what I should be using.  Perhaps a UNION or Subquery?  Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can there be more than one amendment to an order? If so, do you want the last amendment?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are combining data for mutliple rows into one row, you need a *join*:

```
select
    od.PartNo [CAD Appr.?],
    od.DueDate [Appr. Date],
    am.PartNo [Amend. Sent?],
    am.DueDate [Amend. Sent Date]
from OrderDet od
left join OrderDet am on od.PartNo = am.PartNo
    and am.PartNo LIKE 'amend%'
where od.PartNo LIKE 'cad appr%'
order by od.PartNo
```

The `left` join means nulls will be returned for the amendment data.

---

If there can be multiple amendments to an order, and you want the most recent, use this aggregating query:

```
select
    od.PartNo [CAD Appr.?],
    od.DueDate [Appr. Date],
    am.PartNo [Amend. Sent?],
    max(am.DueDate) [Amend. Sent Date]
from OrderDet od
left join OrderDet am on od.PartNo = am.PartNo
    and am.PartNo LIKE 'amend%'
where od.PartNo LIKE 'cad appr%'
group by od.PartNo, od.DueDate, am.PartNo
order by od.PartNo
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, columns 3 and 4 all come back null

Answer (score 0):

A CASE statement works. To not stray too far from your solution, you can GROUP BY the OrderNo, and use MAX() to avoid the null rows:

```
SELECT
    OrderNo,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN PartNo LIKE 'CAD%'
        THEN PartNo
        ELSE null
    END) AS [CAD Appr.?],
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN PartNo LIKE 'CAD%'
        THEN DueDate
        ELSE null
    END) AS [Appr. Date],
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN PartNo LIKE 'Amendment%'
        THEN PartNo
        ELSE null
    END) AS [Amend. Sent],
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN PartNo LIKE 'Amendment%'
        THEN DueDate
        ELSE null
    END) AS [Amend. Sent Date]
FROM [ISOW].[dbo].[OrderDet]
GROUP BY OrderNo
```

Output:

[image: Sql select output]

Comment: This didn't work for me, my amends columns all come back null

Comment: Hm. I ran this on the exact data that was in the screenshot. If you take out the GROUP BY and the MAX()s, do those columns have information half the time? If so, MAX should pick the non-null value from the pair "created" by the GROUP.

Comment: I think the problem is that there's more part numbers than what I presented, just omitted them since they aren't relevant.  My last 2 columns are both totally null for whatever reason